# Windbg - Unable to read memory at ntdll!RtlCriticalSectionList

Tags: windbg

On executing the command "!cs" or "!locks", I encountered the following error:

```
0:000> !locks
NTSDEXTS: Unable to read memory at ntdll!RtlCriticalSectionList
```

**Notes:**

- Windows Debugger Version is 10.0.20153.1000.
- ntdll File version: 6.3.9600.18895

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.mighr.com/it/ky/248/304519.html Probably the code was badly written and the critical section you wanted to debug was not even initialized.

Comment: @LexLi: I think you should give this as an answer

Comment: @LexLi And this is why you don't post links in stackoverflow... that link is down..

Comment: @OneAndOnly You might ask ChatGPT instead, as it accumulates most comprehensive knowledge on WinDbg than any other tool today. The most important hint was my words, not the actual link.